# Mongo Aggregation problem, want to avoid outter wrapper

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

my goal is to update the active property within the weeks object, instead i get another object wrapper.

How i can either avoid this behavior or rewrite the aggregation to get the values from the weeks object in the wrapper?

```
    {
        "weeks": {
            "time": [
                "06",
                "00"
            ],
            "active": true,
            "reason": "",
            "bookTime": 202102260600,
            "qdate": 20210226,
            "booked": false
        },
        "active": false
    },
]
```

My aggregation pipeline:

```
const company = await Company.aggregate([
    { $match: { email: 'test@gmail.com' } },
    { $unwind: '$weeks' },
    { $match: { 'weeks.qdate': { $gte: 20210226, $lte: 20210305 } } },
    { $unset: '_id' },
    {
      $project: {
        weeks: 1,
        active: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $lt: ['$weeks.bookTime', 202102261445] },
            then: false,
            else: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: can you also show/add/define what kind of format are you expecting in the output?

Comment: Thanks i forgot about the $ sign in nested objects, answer is below

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that i need to add the $ sign on nested objects.

So the final pipeline will look like this.

```
const company = await Company.aggregate([
    { $match: { email: 'test@gmail.com' } },
    { $unwind: '$weeks' },
    { $match: { 'weeks.qdate': { $gte: 20210226, $lte: 20210305 } } },
    { $unset: '_id' },
    // { $group: { _id: { time: '$weeks.bookTime' } } },
    {
      $project: {
        bookTime: '$weeks.bookTime',
        utc: '$weeks.utc',
        booked: '$weeks.booked',
        active: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $lt: ['$weeks.bookTime', 202102261445] },
            then: false,
            else: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```